# Wordpress Website is very slow after migration

Tags: plugins, performance

I am using an custom domain to produce a website for my customers. When the draft is finished and the customer happy, I transfer the website to the customers new domain.

For this process I was using a Wordpress plugin "WPVivid". The website was sucessfully copied to the new domain but the loading speed is horrible.

I really have no idea why? The same website was loading just perfectly fine on my "Custom Domain"...

This is the website i am taling about: [www.evahopfgartner.at](http://www.evahopfgartner.at)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll have to ask the hosting company about this.